# Notepad++ process hangs shortly after start; it is suddenly starting ONLY as Administrator

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I've been using Notepad++ for years now. Since a short while, Notepad++ doesn't start anymore (maybe since a recent Windows Update? Or maybe a plugin update?). The process shows up in the task manager, but it seems to stop executing with a consumed CPU time of less than a second.

However, after re-installing it (V6.9.2) (and also trying the previous version 6.9.1, same effect), I noticed that it *does* start as usual when executed as Administrator. *Note:* The behavior is different than the question "[NotePad++ only runs as Administrator or not at all](https://superuser.com/questions/830167/notepad-only-runs-as-administrator-or-not-at-all)" - in that case notepad++ requests Admin rights when started, in my case it doesn't start at all.

I also tried to start it without plugins using the -noPlugins command line option. No effect.

Any idea what could be the cause? What else could I try to reset?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. however, it is something different, I updated the question to explain the difference. Is the explaination clear?

Comment: Correct command-line argument would be `-noPlugin` instead of `-noPlugins`. Retry and let's know if that works. And remember command-line argument may be case-sensitive -- you need to type exactly as mentioned in help.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, it starts when using `-noPlugin`. The docu I found seems to be wrong: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches

Comment: Sounds like it could be a permissions problem

Comment: Glad that helped. Didn't notice that the official page mentions an incorrect command-line.

Comment: In case someone with write access to the notepad++ wiki reads this: Would be nice if you verify the -noPlugin option and correct it on http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notepad++ did start as normal user with the `-noPlugin` switch, thanks to @w32sh's comment. With some try & error I removed several plugins (when started as Admin): At the end, it did start again once I removed the `Explorer` plugin.

Would be interesting to know why this plugin suddently did fail, as it was working well before .......

**EDIT** - there's a discussion about this issue in the N++ forum: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/203/np-not-run-with-explorer-plugin-installed and with a longer discussion https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12253/failure-to-launch/18

It seems that DropBox is causing this problem.

Comment: PS: I uninstalled the Explorer plugin now, so I can't check this - but I remember vaguely that there was a setting in the plugin to use the Windows Explorer icons. Maybe, I did select this which caused the problem ...(and maybe in combination with the DropBox icon overlays)? Well, just an idea. Would also explain that another user (in this case the Administrator) works, as this user did not select this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Correct command-line argument would be `-noPlugin` instead of `-noPlugins`.

Retry and let's know if that works. And remember command-line argument may be case-sensitive -- you need to type exactly as mentioned in help.