# Disable all UAC limitations permanently

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I know it can be a bad idea *in general*, but for a specific case (a music production computer, not connected to internet), I would like to totally disable Windows 10's UAC limitations and Windows 10's User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI).

**Why?** Because I had [several problems](https://superuser.com/questions/1172989/why-doesnt-usual-dragdrop-work-in-windows-10) when trying to use a few software with Windows 10.

The solutions seem [rather complicated](https://superuser.com/questions/1172989/why-doesnt-usual-dragdrop-work-in-windows-10#comment1695681_1173245), that's why I would like to disable these annoying limitations, that I don't need. Everything works fine on my non-internet computer with Win7, so why would it be a problem with Win10?

**How to totally disable Windows 10's UAC limitations and Windows 10's User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)?**

Comment: Windows 10 is very different from windows 8. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken I also agree, please vote to reopen (I also did), and maybe we can have it available to be answered again.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options** in the **local group policy editor**, there are a number of UAC options to alter. I believe the one you may want could be:

> User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account

the option to disable it does:

> Disabled: (Default) The built-in Administrator account runs all applications with full administrative privilege.

There are a number of other UAC-specific options in there that affect how it works.

I hope this helped, please let me know if it did (this was my first contribution to SU)

Comment: Doesn't work anymore on Windows 10 1803.