# Notepad++ stuck in Administrator mode, no solution but found a clue

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, administrator, uac

I've notepad++ stuck in Administrator mode:
[stuck in Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6w4.png)

Debug info:

> Notepad++ v7.9.1   (64-bit)
> Build time : Nov  2 2020 - 01:07:46
> Path : C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
> Admin mode : ON
> Local Conf mode : OFF
> OS Name : Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit)
> OS Version : 1809
> OS Build : 17763.1518
> Current ANSI codepage : 1252
> Plugins : mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll NppExport.dll

### How it happened:

1. installed notepad++
2. launched it
3. installed two plugins (xml tools and xml treeview) while connected to a VPN
4. download filed due to VPN
5. stopped the VPN and installed the plugins again
6. closed and re-opened notepad++
7. is now stuck in administrator mode (no UAC prompt)

### What I tried:

1. uninstalling and reinstalling;
2. uninstalling, cleaning all regkeys(*) that I found for notepad++, reinstalling;
3. uninstalling, installing different versions (different builds/bit);
4. checked these keys for runas command:

   - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe --> runas not present
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\notepad++.ex --> runas not present
5. [everything in this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/830167/notepad-only-runs-as-administrator-or-not-at-all/841192#:%7E:text=9%2C%20and%20this%20fix%20resolved,be%20able%20to%20do%20this.);
6. [everything in this other thread](https://superuser.com/questions/547810/how-to-turn-off-always-run-as-administrator-windows-8-10).

Nothing worked.

(*) "Suspicious" regkeys:

- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatability Assistant\Store
- HKU<my-user-sid>\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatability Assistant\Store

---

**The clue:** renaming the executable "notepad++.exe" to "_notepad++.exe" or "notepad++_test.exe" solves the problem entirely and can run it as a normal user.

---

I suspect that there is a list of "names" that Windows uses to just run something as an Administrator but can't find it anywhere.
Also renaming the installer and running it shows the UAC prompt, with the original name it starts as Administrator without prompting anything.

Any tips/hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to verify, if you rename the exe back and you run it, the problem comes back, right?

Comment: What is your UAC level set to in Windows?

Comment: @LPChip: yes, exactly as you described.
Tried renaming another program to "notepad++.exe" but it started normally.

Comment: @spikey_richie: is set at its max level "Always notify" (I've it in Italian and that's my translation).
Indeed when running other programs that needs admin rights the UAC prompt popup.
The Notepad++ installer comes up in "Administrator" mode too and without UAC, if I rename the installer the UAC prompt pops up.

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious in the "virtual stores" `HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`?

Comment: @Wolf nothing, there are some entries about other software but totally unrelated to notepad++.
Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different solutions, I found this worked for me:

1. Right-click on the notepad++.exe file, select Properties.
2. Click on the Compatibility tab, and select “Run this program in compatibility mode for:” and select “Windows 8”.
3. Make sure “Run this program as an administrator” is unchecked.
4. Click OK.

However, this work-around was not working when I tried to run Notepad++ via an AutoHotKey shortcut; it still ran as Administrator. So here is another work-around using Windows Task Scheduler:

1. Open the Windows Start menu, search for “task scheduler”, and run that.
2. Click on the “Task Scheduler Library” item in the tree view on the left.
3. Click on the Action menu, then “Create Task…”. Type in a name for your task.
4. Under the General tab, click the “Change User or Group…” button.
5. Type in “Users” in the “Enter the object name to select” box and click OK.
6. Click on the Actions tab, then click on the “New…” button.
7. Click on the “Browse…” button, and find your notepad++.exe file and open that.
8. Click on the Settings tab and make sure “Allow task to be run on demand” is checked.
9. Click OK.
10. To make a batch file to run this scheduled task, you can put this command in a text file and name it with a “.bat” extension:

    ```
    schtasks /run /tn <name of your task from step 3 here>
    ```